# How to move element smoothly?

Tags: javascript, scroll

In this template
https://themify.me/demo/themes/parallax/
after full width slider
when you scroll, element move smoothly with a little delay In their section
and after stop scroll, element still keep moving
 exactly like this section: 
 themify.me/demo/themes/parallax/#services
do you know any JavaScript plugin that create this effect? 
and I must emphasize move background not! 
move element
like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a little searching on the web, it depends on what CSS framework you are using. You may read this article for a general way of doing it. (No javascript)
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

(Can't comment, so I'll leave the link here.)

Comment: i edited my topic and show you what i want in picture

Comment: Check the demo: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax
With proper styling and markup, you can replicate your demo.

Comment: tnx i checked it but i didn't know how to create that effect,please show me with code

Answer (score 0):

what's mean 'hero header' if mean navigation bar so try this  :

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Comment: means full width slider

Comment: ok you can use `waypoints` and `animate.css` waypoint for scroll and animate for animation show
[waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) &
[animate](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: i checked it but i didn't know how implement that effect.please show me with example code.tnx

Comment: tnx.but i want when i scroll element move exactly like this section https://themify.me/demo/themes/parallax/#services

Comment: tnx very close.and now as you can see in that link i want when scroll top element move down and when scroll down element move up and four element have different position and just move on their section not move in all body.like services in themify